# How to compute the limit?

Tags: limits

If 
$\sqrt{[\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty (x_{k}^{(n)}-x_k)^2]}\rightarrow 0 ~(n\rightarrow \infty)$
,and 
$x_k^{(n)}\rightarrow 0, ~x_k\rightarrow 0$ $(k\rightarrow \infty)$.
How to show that
$$
\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}k(\max\{|x_k^{(n)}|-1,0\}-\max\{|x_k|-1,0\})\rightarrow 0
~(n\rightarrow \infty)
$$

Comment: Under the assumption, the sum in question is finite, so the role of $k$ is not clear. The result follows from the pointwise convergence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No longer valid as $x_k^n$ has been changed to $x_k^{(n)}$**

If $\exists j$ such that $x_{j} \not\in \{-1, 0 ,1 \}$ we have when $n \to \infty$ that $(x_j^n - x_j)^2 \to x_j^2$ if $|x_j|<1$ and $(x_j^n  -x_j)^2 \to \infty$ if $|x_j|>1$.
Since we have $\sum_{k=1}^\infty (x_k^n - x_k)^2 \ge (x_j^n - x_j)^2$, we have $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{ \sum_{k=1}^\infty (x_k^n - x_k)^2 } \ge \lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{ (x_j^2 - x_j)^2} = \left\{ \begin{matrix} |x_j| & |x_j| < 1 \\ \infty  & |x_j| > 1 \end{matrix}\right.$$ 
Since $x_j \neq 0$, we have $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{ \sum_{k=1}^\infty (x_k^n - x_k)^2 } >0$, which contradicts $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{ \sum_{k=1}^\infty (x_k^n - x_k)^2 }=0$.

So we have $x_j \in \{ -1, 0 ,1\}$ for all $j \in \mathbb{N}$. This yields $$\max\{ |x_k^n| -1, 0\} - \max \{ |x_k | - 1 , 0\} = 0$$

So the last sum is equal to $0$ for any value of $n$, so clearly its limit is also $0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: why we have when $n\rightarrow \infty$......I don't understand the first paragraph.I think we always have $(x_j^n-x_j)^2\rightarrow x_j^2 ~~(n\rightarrow \infty)$

Comment: If $|x_k| < 1$, we have $x_k^n \to 0$ when $n \to \infty$, so $\lim_{n \to \infty} (x_k^n - x_k)^2  = (\lim_{n \to \infty} x_k^n - x_k )^2 = (-x_k + \lim_{n \to \infty} x_k^n)^2 = x_k^2$. If $|x_k |>1$, we have $\lim_{n \to \infty } x_k^n = \pm \infty$, so we have $\lim_{n \to \infty} (x_k^n - x_k)^2 = (\pm \infty - x_k)^2= \infty$.

Comment: why if $|x_k|>1$, we have $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} x_k^n=\pm\infty$?

Comment: Let me restate that: If $|x_k| >1$, we can for all $L \in \mathbb{N}$ find an $N$ such that $n \ge N$ implies $|x_k^n| \ge L$. So in particular, we have $|x_k^n - x_k | \ge L - |x_k|$, and thus $|x_k^n - x_k| \to \infty$ since $x_k$ is fixed. Now, then we have $(x_k^n - x_k)^2 = |x_k^n - x_k|^2 \to \infty$.

Comment: Consider for example $x_1 = 2$, and see how $2^n-2$ behaves as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Oh, I'm really sorry, the $x_k^n$ is not Nth power, I have edit it . I'm really sorry.

Comment: @lanse2pty If you know the solution, feel free to post it and accept that as an answer.